# DataReader error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

My code was working fine until when I added parameters. Since then I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in NewMonitoringSystem.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I need help on how to fix this error.
Here's my code: ***Error on LINE 10 of this code***

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    frmMainMenu.Height = 720
    frmMainMenu.Width = 950
    Dim numID As Integer = 2
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, username, password FROM tblUsers WHERE username = @username and password = @password"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = txtUsername.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = txtPassword.Text
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        If dr("ID") = numID Then
            Me.Hide()
            frmMainMenu.lblAccessLevel.Text = "Admin"
            frmMainMenu.Show()
        Else
            Me.Hide()
            frmMainMenu.lblAccessLevel.Text = "User"
            frmMainMenu.TSMOffertory.Enabled = False
            frmMainMenu.TSMOffertory.Visible = False
            frmMainMenu.Show()
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid Credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Invalid LogIn")
    End If
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line of code did the error occured in your debug session ?

Comment: What is dr and where is its declaration and creation ?

Comment: @GuidoG dr was declared after _Public Class MyForm_  **Dim cmd As New SqlCommand**  **Dim dr As SqlDataReader**

Comment: you should put that in your question so other readers can see it without having to read all the comments

Comment: And where is the code that executes the cmd command ? And the declaration of cmd ? Can you please post all relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Found the solution. Just added that line after parameters.